# Javascript regex for splitting by whitespace for accented chars

Tags: javascript, regex

I am trying to split string in javascript by whitespaces, but ignoring whitespaces enclosed in quotes. So I googled this regular expression :`(/\w+|"[^"]+"/g)` but the problem is, that this isn't working with accented chars like á etc. So please how should I improve my regular expression to make it work?

Comment: Can the string include quotes nested within quotes?  If so, regex may not be the way to go.  See this previous answer: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/133601/can-regular-expressions-be-used-to-match-nested-patterns

Comment: no the quotes are used only to mark word that shouldn't be splitted, the problem is only with accented chars

Comment: @david, are you using `split` or `exec`. If you're using the former then that regular expression is not what you want and in that case you should use the latter

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This matches non-spaces that don't contain quotes, and matches text between quotes:

```
/[^\s"]+|"[^"]+"/g
```

Answer (score 1):

That's because `\w` only matches `[A-Za-z0-9_]`. To match **accented** characters, add the unicode block range `\x81-\xFF` which includes the Latin-1 characters `à` and `ã`, *et cetera*:

```
(/[\w\x81-\xFF]+|"[^"]+"/g)
```

There's also [this](http://kourge.net/projects/regexp-unicode-block) site, which is very helpful to build the required unicode block range.

Answer (score 0):

If you want to match all non-whitespace characters instead of only alphanumeric ones, replace `\w` with `\S`.

Comment: If the string contains `"foo bar"` this will separately match `"foo` and `bar"`, whereas I think he'd want to match `"foo bar"`.  I used `[^\s"]` in my answer to avoid this.

Comment: Right, thanks for the hint. `/"[^"]+"|\S+/g` should work as well